# Vb.NET Start Process and return output

Tags: vb.net, process

I'm trying to execute some command line commands (putty). Now it may be that the command line waits for an input (simplest example: password maybe wrong). All the output should be written into Console.

My code displays a non-ending command line that does not write anything to the console.

```
Imports System.Text

Public Class Form1
    Private Shared processOutput As StringBuilder = Nothing
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim line As String = "/c plink -ssh chef@192.168.178.35 -pw 12345678 -m C:\putty\pw\putty.txt"
        processOutput = New StringBuilder()
        Dim objP As New System.Diagnostics.Process()
        Dim objPi As ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo()
        With objPi
            .FileName = "cmd.exe"
            .Arguments = line
            .RedirectStandardOutput = True
            .RedirectStandardError = True
            .RedirectStandardInput = True
            .UseShellExecute = False
            .WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
            .CreateNoWindow = False
        End With
        objP.StartInfo = objPi

        AddHandler objP.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf OutputHandler
        objP.Start()
        objP.BeginOutputReadLine()
        objP.WaitForExit(1000)
        Debug.WriteLine(processOutput.ToString())
    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub OutputHandler(sendingProcess As Object, outLine As DataReceivedEventArgs)
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(outLine.Data) Then
            processOutput.AppendLine(outLine.Data)
        End If
    End Sub


End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Stephen mentioned, your are not printing anything to the console, only writing to the StringBuilder object. So you have to print the content of StringBuilder object to the console to actually see a result:

```
Console.WriteLine(processOutput)
```

MSDN example see:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 0):

it's because you're not writing anything to console or the UI. Debug.write is not the same as console.write

Additionally, your delegate function may be returning after 1 second. A better paradigm would use await.

```
Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click  
    ' Call the method that runs asynchronously.  
    Dim result As String = Await WaitAsynchronouslyAsync()  

    ' Call the method that runs synchronously.  
    'Dim result As String = Await WaitSynchronously()  

    ' Display the result.  
    TextBox1.Text &= result  
End Sub  

' The following method runs asynchronously. The UI thread is not  
' blocked during the delay. You can move or resize the Form1 window   
' while Task.Delay is running.  
Public Async Function WaitAsynchronouslyAsync() As Task(Of String)  
    Await Task.Delay(10000)  
    Return "Finished"  
End Function  

' The following method runs synchronously, despite the use of Async.  
' You cannot move or resize the Form1 window while Thread.Sleep  
' is running because the UI thread is blocked.  
Public Async Function WaitSynchronously() As Task(Of String)  
    ' Import System.Threading for the Sleep method.  
    Thread.Sleep(10000)  
    Return "Finished"  
End Function
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/await-operator